# Como apagar de todos os commits um arquivo?

Tags: git

No meu primeiro commit enviei um arquivo binario que não tem motivo de ficar.
E enviei um arquivo de configuração com senhas verdadeiras.
Eu alterei a senha pra uma falsa, apaguei o binário, mas se voltar a um commit antigo os dados ainda estão lá.

Não queria apagar o repositório e iniciar um novo perdendo o meu histórico de meses trabalhados pra esconder esse pequeno deslise. Mas preciso que realmente esses 2 arquivos fiquem irrecuperáveis.

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar o [filter-branch](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/) para isto.

Primeiro, precisa rastrear os commits que contém este arquivo:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch CAMINHO-PARA-SEU-ARQUIVO-COM-SENHAS' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Adicione o arquivo no `.gitignore` (se desejar manter este arquivo de senhas apenas localmente):

```
echo "SEU-ARQUIVO-COM-SENHAS" >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Add SEU-ARQUIVO-COM-SENHAS to .gitignore"
```

Se estiver tudo certo e seu repositório estiver disponível remotamente (exemplo, no Github), faça um `push` para sobrescrever no repositório todas as alterações:

```
git push origin --force --all
```

Faça o mesmo com as tags, se tiver usado alguma tag no período que o arquivo com senhas estava disponível:

```
git push origin --force --tags
```

**Recomendo** fazer um backup do repositório antes de proceder com as dicas acima.

Comment: Nossa parece que entendi muito bem o que ele queria não, +1!